# Can't add User.IsInRole("") inside of a controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Currently I'm having a lot of trouble programming in MVC. I made this query, which works perfectly for me. It only shows the reservations of the location where the currently logged in user works at. BUT, only a manager and an administrator has a location, because the administrator should be able to check them all, and shouldn't be blocked out.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, Manager, Gebruiker")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using {
            if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                var userid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                var filiaaltje = db.UserVestiging.Where(x => x.UserId == userid).Select(x => x).Single();
                var userReserveringen = db.Reserveringen.Where(x => x.Vestiging.Contains(filiaaltje.Vestiging)).Select(x => x).ToList();
                return View(userReserveringen);
            }
        }
```

The model that I'm using:

[image]

Any possible fix for this?

Comment: fix for what exactly? You're explicitly checking for the current User ID and passing it to your query. If you don't want to do that in certain circumstances, then write code which checks the circumstances and doesn't pass the ID in that scenario. You say "can't add User.IsInRole"...but why not? Show what you tried for that, and what error you got. It should be possible.

Comment: Your method uses a parameter 'vestiging', but you never use it.

Comment: That parameter is an old one, shouldn't be there anymore. A little more information: The query checks at which location the user works. The administrator doesn't have a location, because he should be allowed to check all the reservations and do everything with them. But right now, if the code runs and I'm logged in with an administrator account it errors out, and stops the program. I edited the post with some code that I tried.

Comment: "it errors out". What's the error? There could be all sorts of reasons for it, we can't just guess. Just saying there's an error is not useful information to anyone.

Comment: You need to explain your issue in detail - you haven't done that yet.